# How to iterate through data set in pandas based on days?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```py
data 

for label, content in data.items():
   print('label:', label)
   print('content:', content, sep='\n')`
```

That is all. IGNORE IT

Comment: Can you show us how `data` looks like?

Comment: just added how it looks like from print in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset by index

```
data2 = data.loc[(data.index.month == 11) & (data.index.day == 10)]
```

You index is `datetime` type, and you want it converted to string. First we need to reset_index

```
data2 = data2.reset_index()
data2["Date"] = data2["Date"].astype(str)
```

Then get the rows as list of lists (your example output)

```
data2.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to [split](https://www.interviewqs.com/ddi_code_snippets/extract_month_year_pandas) the date into three columns :"Year","Month","Day".
Then simply do a selection like

```
newdf=df[df["Day"]==20 & df["Month"]==11]
```

Then you can perform your analysis on this new df.

To translate the code it means "copy all the values from df where Month is 11 and Day is 20"